# How to add a variable in Directory MSI table using msilib

Tags: python, windows-installer, installation, setup.py

I want to use a path edit control in my setup application I am designing using Python msilib. But I am getting an error in the MSI saying:

```
The specified path is unavailable.
```

Can somebody help me find the reason for this? I think I haven't made any entry in the Directory table which can cause the error. How can I do it using msilib?

Comment: Can you show us the related code? How about the exact error message, and when you get it? We need more details to be able to help you!

Comment: p = sys.argv[1]
f = open("C:\\temp.txt", "a")
f.write(p)
f.close() butit is taking path like "C:\ProgramFiles" which is not accessible. What should I make to get "C:\Program Files"

Answer (score 0):

This is MSI error: 1314 http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa372835(v=vs.85).aspx

This can happen if the path that you've specified is invalid (perhaps you have a space in the name like C:\Program Files and should enclose it in quotes like "C:\Program Files") or this error can also happen if you are specifying a path that already exists.